# How to get the current product's variant ID?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How do I get the variant ID of a product I'm currently viewing? For example, if I'm viewing a product at `example.com/collections/bowls/product-name?variant=123456789` I need to get the variant's ID number. I've tried `{{ variant.id }}` but it does not return anything. I can get it to return all of the variant ID's when I put it within a `{% for variant in product.variants %}` loop but that returns all of the IDs. I just need the ID of the one I'm currently viewing.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ product.selected_variant.id }}
```

Comment: You might actually want to use `product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id` - as I understand it, `selected_variant` is null if there's no variant in the URL of the page you are on.

Comment: {{ product.selected_variant.id }} is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

if you are using javascript you can get variant id of selected variant from the product page with querySelector.

document.querySelector('.product__pickup-availabilities').dataset.variantId

it works for both conditions(with variants or not),

Comment: The solution in the answer is not what is asked in the question.

Comment: Although! It worked for first time but didn't provide updated result. `window.location.search.split('variant=')[1]` will provide updated variant id.